# Listener for Download Dialog created Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a download manager and now I am creating its extensions. For firefox extension the problem is that I cannot find a decent way in which I can listen for creation of download and then stop the creation and redirect the url to my application. So here are two approaches I have already tried along with their drawbacks:

**1. Using Downloads.jsm**

```js
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

let list;
let view = {
    onDownloadAdded: download => {
        Task.spawn(function () {
            try {
                // Send download.source.url to my application
                yield download.finalize(true);
                yield list.remove(download);
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error(ex);
            }
        });
    }
};

Task.spawn(function () {
    list = yield Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);
    yield list.addView(view);

}).then(null, Cu.reportError);

exports.onUnload = function (reason) {
    list.removeView(view);
};
```

**Problem:** The problem with this approach is that user have to 1st click save as dialog then click start button on my download manager which is totally unacceptable. If I have to use this approach I need some way to remove this save as dialog. And because I am canceling download when its added the download is shown as canceled in "Show all downloads" dialog in firefox.

**2. Using http-on-modify-request**

```js
var dlExtensions = [".exe", ".iso"];

const {components, Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
httpRequestObserver =
{
    observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
        if (aTopic == "http-on-modify-request") {
            let url;

            aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            url = aSubject.URI.spec;

            for (var x in dlExtensions) {
                if (url.endsWith(dlExtensions[x])) {
                    aSubject.cancel(components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
                    // Send url to my application
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var observerService = components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false);
```

**Problem:** This code works as expected but the problem is I have to define all download Extensions of file to download and there are too many of them.

**Requirement:** So basically I need a listener that listens for creation of download in firefox and a way in which I can stop regular download dialog appearing and make my code execute instead.(Note that the listener present in method 1 is not useable because it listens for addition of download in download list not for the creation of download that leads to creation of download dialog)